# Is there a method where i can erase text in Pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, erase, pygame-surface

I am developing a simple game where there is a part in it that needs to erase some text after a certain amount of time. I did some research but i am not able to find any methods or functions on how i would be able to do that. It would be great if it was a method that could only erase the text and not the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can "erase" things in pygame by blitting the part of background that goes into the specific spot.

If the background is all just a color, you can draw on that spot with the color.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am a bit confused. The background has some objects that move (LOL i am a beginner i cannot make a scrolling background yet). If you could elaborate more that would be awesome.

Answer (score -2):

You should create a variable called `text` or something like that and set it to true when you want it to be shown and set it to false when you want it to disappear. You can do this with a while loop:

```
while text:
    pass
    # display your text here
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to try to answer questions where you can provide real, working, concrete code - your too high level approach here, on a technology that deducting from your answer is easy to know you are not familiar with, would do nothing to help the author of the question. As much as I like welcoming people to Stackoverflow, I have to downvote this.